# SwingWorker never return anything? (java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

sorry i'm newbie in this **Java Swing interfaces.**

But I found a simple tutorial that I can follow upon. [Here Link1.](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=38)

So then I created a simple JFrame and a button.
Once the button is pressed it will do these code:

```
 int res = -1;
    
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", jTextField1.getText()));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", jTextField2.getText()));
    
    Submitter m = new Submitter();
    m.setData(urlParameters);
    m.setURL(url1);
    
    m.execute(); System.out.println(m.getResult);
```

Whereas the Submitter clas is actually this one:

```
public class Submitter extends SwingWorker<String, Void> {

public int getResult(){
return res;
}

String line = "";
String urlTarget;
int res = -1;
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

public String getLastResult(){
    return result.toString();
}

public void setURL(String yourURL){
    urlTarget = yourURL;
}

public void setData(List<NameValuePair> listHere){
    nameValuePairs.addAll(listHere);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlTarget);
    try {

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Firefox");
        
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.toString();
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        // store the output here
        String s = this.get();
        res = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("line 119");
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        System.err.println("line 121" + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

But the funny thing is. That SwingWorker that is intended to be called once the button is pressed, it is never process anything. Why there's no output at all? i thought I already put the System.out.println() -> over there. CMIIW.

Comment: It looks like you need to [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel%28boolean%29) the `SwingWorker` in order to see any output.

Comment: cancel the swingworker? Why ? i mean, it doesnt make me understand. First we EXecute, then we Cancel suddenly?

Comment: This particular code seems to loop indefinitely until cancelled. That's not how you'd normally write a `SwingWorker`, but it explains why you don't see any output. Alternatively, perform some work inside your `while` loop and eventually return a string result.

Comment: @Duncan you're right. Now I tried to adjust the content a bit upper. But still the content is not available. Is that because of the while loop that never ends?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've taken the example presented in the tutorial a little too literally. In a real-life, your `SwingWorker` would be performing a well defined piece of work before returning a result. I think this tutorial was simply trying to demonstrate that a `SwingWorker` can be interrupted if you check for the `isCancelled()` flag.

As an exercise, you could try adjusting the example to [iteratively calculate Pi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiIterations.html) to ever increasing accuracy. When you finally hit "Stop", it could cancel the worker and return your current value. Until you cancel, the loop would continue executing and refining your answer.

Comment: thanks for it. Duncan, now i modify a bit for the code. 
Seems the looping doesnt finished. Is this due to my mistake or something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a java newbie too. I found a great java book which I downloaded for free. Do a Google search for "Java Programming Joyce Farrell 6th Edition pdf". I've only been learning java for 3 months and that book has helped a lot.